# Store uri of raw folder's files into ArrayList<String>

Tags: android, arraylist, uri, android-imageview, filenotfoundexception

I have 120 images that I have stored in raw folder. I did this on purpose . And please do not suggest me about putting those in `drawable` and so on. To store the `uri` of each file into an `Arraylist` of `String` I have used following way/method.

```
private static void getRawFiles() throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException{
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] fields = R.raw.class.getFields(); // fileds stores resid and 
        // loop for every file in raw folder

        if (uriCollection.isEmpty()){

        for (int count = 0; count < fields.length; count++) {
            String filename ="android.resource://" +HomeActivity.PACKAGE_NAME + "/"+"R.raw."+ "_"+count;


            uriCollection.add(filename);
            Log.i("fileUri",filename);


        }
        }
```

The file name in raw folder starts with `_0._01` and so on. So I have accessed this from another `class` and `setImageURI` to display images in the `ImageView`. But I have been getting following errors as well as application stops

```
- resolvedUri failed on bad bitmap
- unable to open content; filenotfoundexception
```

If you have any ideas or any solution or if you have come across such problem then  i would like to kindly request for your assistance. Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Can you work with Reource Ids? I usually do this to dynamically get at files.

In your loop - you will have to decide how you generate the `imageName` - generate your imageName and call:

```
        String imageName = "_0.01";//OBSERVE it's not "_0.01.jpg"
        int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
        aListOfResourceIDs.add(resId);
```

Comment: I can not use the resid because i have to update this arraylist later on to put new uri of the image.

Comment: Alright, when you do get the Exception, print out which file name you were using (or uri) and check if it's on file.